# Cancel ALL Animation on SingleInstance

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, themes, single-instance

I am wondering if its at all possible to cancel ALL animation when starting an singleInstance activity,
i am already using

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

for when finish is called and

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

to activate it... but theres still a black screen ( short loading one). trying creating a costume Theme and didnt cancel it.

i kinda gave up hope... I know fragments will solve it.
is there any way without?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling  `overridePendingTransition` after calling `startActivity(...)`

You can also disable animations via themes

Developer should create a style,

```
<style name="noAnimTheme" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

then in manifest set it as theme for activity or whole application.

```
<activity android:name=".ui.ArticlesActivity" android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme">
</activity>
```

You can also specify a style to specify custom entry and exit animations, so you can make it do what you like as well
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowEnterAnimation

Comment: yes man...i tried creating a no theme and then onCreate adding the theme.(There must be a theme in the Activity),so i tried both solutions...maybe I didnt explain it well enough in the question...

Comment: Try using the XML above to apply it to the activity using the XML above in your manifest. The android:name must be named after your activity including the package path.

Comment: Did you try it? does it work for you? because when i tried it (still using it) canceling animation and theme and then on create creating a theme programmatically still i got a dark screen while loading...for 500ms or so... but its there

Comment: It works for me but I'm wondering if it's to do with manufacturers installing their own skin on top, which version of Android / Device are you testing on ? You could try making your own animation via `windowEnterAnimation` which makes it instantly appear ? See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowEnterAnimation or you can watch this https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DHo8vk61lVIU&ei=s3tVUvKAI_Sr0AX944D4DA&usg=AFQjCNEYV4MHlDjCwm0ypc1d1XPlTJZZOg&bvm=bv.53760139,d.d2k